# Red Dead Revolver freeze / black screen on Xbox 360

Tags: xbox-360, red-dead-revolver

While playing on Xbox 360 at the Xbox version of Red Dead Revolver (via backward compatibility) the game often freeze at the beginning of some levels (lvl 12 for sure, maybe lvl 18 also), it results in a black screen and the only way to escape this is to restart the Xbox 360. The game also freeze during level 8 during the boss fight with Bad Bessie.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that the game is not well emulated on Xbox 360 while playing in 1080p. You can also notice some visual glitches especially in loading screens.

To fix these problems (glitches in loading screens and black screens just before starting levels) : Go to the settings of your Xbox set the resolution to `480p` and set the screen format/mode to `normal` instead of `large`. As the original Xbox games doesn't support high definition (720p+) it won't causes visual degradation.

For the `Bad bessie` freeze in the chapter's 8 boss fight : what I observed is that the game only crash/freeze during this boss fight if you are close to `Bad Bessie` so to avoid the bug : don't go in the arena stay on the "stair" at the beginning of the level and shoot at her when she gets reachable (using this strategy could be long). To force `Bad Bessie` to move and not hide you will have to go in the arena for a short time. As soon as she talks, she will move, go back to the stair.

The way I handle this boss fight is that I was lucky enough to stuck her out of the arena in the stair so I only have to shoot as she wasn't moving. She get stuck while she was following me after I attracted her by going inside the arena.